# How does one install a setup.cfg + pyproject.toml python project in editable mode with pip?

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, pep517

Is it possible to halve your cake and eat it too: can one install (via some mechanism) a project with the following structure:

```
pyproject.toml
setup.cfg
src/...
scripts/...
```

In editable mode, like one could with a standard `setup.py` project:

```
python3 -m pip install -e .
```

(It is OK if the answer is: "**one does not install pyproj.toml packages in editable mode**")

Comment: There's _probably_ a way using Dephell, https://dephell.org/ ...

Comment: @AKX nice project link. Thanks man.

Comment: This should just work. Can you show your `setup.cfg` and `pyproject.toml` files?

Comment: With [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621/) and [PEP 660](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/), you will be able to use `pyproject.toml` for everything. As of Pip version 21.1, [you don't need a dummy `setup.py` anymore](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1688#issuecomment-902794116). For older Pip versions, you need a [dummy `setup.py`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1688#issuecomment-902784345).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***UPDATE:*** As of August 2022, Setuptools and Pip now fully support PEP 660, and therefore it is now possible to perform an editable installation with *only* `pyproject.toml`.

***NOTE:*** To be able to do an editable installation to your *user* site (`pip install -e --user`), you need a *system* installed `setuptools` [v62.0.0 or newer](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3019#issuecomment-1264613828).

---

After Pip version 21.1, you can use `setup.cfg` for editable installs.

In the near future, you won't even need *that*, because there is finally a standard for editable installs that doesn't assume you're using Setuptools: [PEP 660](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0660/). When PEP-517-compatible build backends start also supporting PEP 660, then Pip editable installation will work on projects that *only* have a `pyproject.toml`, i.e. PEP-517-only projects that don't support the legacy Setuptools interface (`setup.py`/`setup.cfg`).

Before Pip version 21.1 you needed a [dummy `setup.py`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1688#issuecomment-902784345):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import setuptools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setuptools.setup()
```

Comment: How should I get the `setup.cfg` file?

Comment: You don't "get" the file, it's a config file that you create. It is analogous to `setup.py`.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I have all my config in `pyproject.toml`, so something needs to generate this useless `setup.cfg` for me.